# Best way to keep "hard coded" version number in Git repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have a piece of software (some scripts) on Github. Say, someone downloads the software by the direct link (no cloning, I don't assume the user has Git). How can I achieve that the current version number is displayed when starting the scripts? In case someone really clones the repository this is easy just by running git describe. But, as I said, I don't want to assume that Git is available.

I only found the following solution which is rather annoying and bad. I created a post-commit and a pre-commit hook keeping a file version.txt in the repository up to date as follows:

**pre-commit:**

```
#!/bin/sh

#####################################################
#hook for handling version.txt
#we get the current version number in the form x.y-h, 
#extract x.y and write the next version number
#x.(y+1) to version.txt before push
#####################################################
VER=`git describe --long`
MAIN=`echo $VER | awk -F "-" '/1/ {print $1}'`
SUB=`echo $VER | awk -F "-" '/1/ {print $2}'`
SUBNEXT=$((SUB+1))
echo $MAIN-$SUBNEXT > version.txt
git add version.txt
```

**post-commit:**

```
#!/bin/bash

####################
#update version.txt
####################
git rm -q version.txt
VER=`git describe --long`
echo $VER > version.txt
```

The annoying thing is somehow that version.txt always shows up as untracked file in git status. What's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The way to record the version into a file in git repo is the only available access to the users who have not Git (since they can not read the version by git command).

And to make it more efficient, you can **use pre-push hook instead of pre-commit hook and post-commit hook**.

In the pre-push hook, you just need to update `version.txt` file with the latest version and commit the changes. The script as below:

```
#!/bin/sh

ver=$(git describe --long)
echo $ver > version.txt
git add version.txt
git commit -m 'update version.txt'
echo "update version successful"
```